# Ocaml pattern matching for "square" tuple?

Tags: functional-programming, pattern-matching, ocaml

In attempting to learn Ocaml and functional languages in general, I have been looking into pattern matching. I was reading [this documentation](https://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/oreilly-book/html/book-ora016.html), and decided to try the following exercise for myself:

Make an expression that evaluates to `true` when an integer 4-tuple is input such that each element in the 4-tuple is equal.

(4, 4, 4, 4) -> `true`

(4, 2, 4, 4) -> `false`

I find that doing pattern matching for the specificity of the value of the elements to not be obvious. This is the code I wrote.

```
let sqr x = match x with 
   (a, a, a, a) -> true 
 | (_, _, _, _) -> false ;;
```

Of course, this code throws the following error:

`Error: Variable a is bound several times in this matching`

How else can I not only enforce that x is a 4-tuple, but also of strictly integers that are equal?

(Also, of course a "square" tuple should not allow non-positive integers, but I'm more concerned with the aforementioned problem as of now).
`

Comment: OCaml has only so-called "linear" patterns where each variable shows up once.So a pattern can't enforce equality between different parts of the mateched value.

Comment: Note that you can also pattern-match on functions argument as in the following : ````let sqr (a,b,c,d) = a=b && b=c && c==d```` which may seem more natural

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As you found out, unlike some other languages' pattern-matching systems, you can't do this in OCaml. What you can do is match each element of the tuple separately while using guards to only succeed if some property (like equivalence) holds across them:

```
let sqr x =
  match x with
  | (a, b, c, d) when a = b && b = c && c = d -> `Equal
  | (a, b, c, d) when (a < b && b < c && c < d)
                   || (a > b && b > c && c > d) -> `Ordered
  | _ -> `Boring
```

Comment: Interesting. I'm new to functional programming as a whole. I know Ocaml does type inference, but does your program allow tuples of ``a`` or just `int``? Also, the ``Equal`` and ``Ordered`` are... what? Thanks!

Comment: @TrueAzure Since only comparison operators are used, which are polymorphic in OCaml, `sqr` accepts tuples of any (single) type. `\`Equal` and friends are [polymorphic variants](https://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml-4.06/lablexamples.html#sec46)

Answer (score 1):

You have many ways to do pattern-matching, pattern matching is not only when using the *match* keyword

```
let fourtuple_equals (a,b,c,d) = List.for_all ((=) a) [b;c;d]
val fourtuple_equals : 'a * 'a * 'a * 'a -> bool = <fun>
```

Here you have a pattern matching directly in the parameter in order to access your four elements tuple.

In this example I use a list to have a more concise code, but is not the more efficient.